# Point of marking directories as source / test

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea

What is the point of marking directories as source / test root?

It seems that it sometimes can't find the package if the root isn't marked, printing the following message:

> Package name mismatch. Actual: 'something', expected: 'something'...

By marking the root directory as test, the message disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A source or test root is the root of the package hierarchy. Knowing the location of the root is necessary to resolve references from other modules and to compile the code correctly. Code outside of source roots will not be compiled.